# 4017 IC with tri-state output

Tags: counter

I am looking for an IC whose functionalities would be same as 4017 IC's (that is a ring counter),but in addition to that I want a TRI-STATE output like mechanism (of course on the same chip) which will ensure if we give clock pulse, ***internally*** the bits will shift, but it won't appear at the output until I enable the TRI-STATE buffer/switch. Searched the internet a lot, but not able find such an IC.I want to know if there is one such.

Comment: You should use certainly a PLD or similar device.

Comment: Something as this (5V)  https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/doc0453.pdf

Comment: Chips are cheap. Just use a tristate buffer after the 4017. You could also share what sort of input is that 4017 output feeding: perhaps a tristate buffer is not needed or could be simplified.

Answer (score 1):

That's a bit of a "special thing" that is unlikely to already exist. So, you'll need to construct it yourself.

For digital logic, that kind of problem occurs very often, so there's a couple of common solutions.

The easiest: If the speed of your signal is low (say, below a dozen MHz), a simple microcontroller can do that. Cheap, software-only solution, that can be quickly programmed, and be *very* flexible.
Microcontrollers are actually designed for this kind of task – they come with hardware counters, so that you don't have to do the counting yourself, but only write something that looks for your "latch" input, to change the output. Microcontrollers are plenty quick, so you can do the conversion to ten outputs when its necessary.

If that's not the case, you'll have to look into *reconfigurable logic*. There's PLDs (programmable logic devices), CPLD (complex PLDs), FPGAs, and things like microcontroller integrating such components. Also, Silego GreenPAK might be attractive here, especially if you need a timer or analog components atop of your counter.

Programming (C)PLDs or FPGAs need not be complicated, but it still needs a bit more experience, usually.